# Allow nodejs sessions to carry over to subdomains

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, passport.js

I am struggling with understanding sessions in nodejs, I have a sub domain on the same port but I have to login again.

I was wondering how do I configure nodejs to share the same session, I am using passportjs to log the users in.

I have tried using redis, but it does not work, I do not understand it.

```
app.use(session({ 
  secret: "something", 
  domain: '.app.localhost',
  store : new RedisStore({
    host: '.app.localhost',
    port : 9200 ,
    client: redisClient
  }),
  cookie : {
    maxAge : 604800 // one week
  }
}));
```

How the heck do I get my subdomain app.localhost to share the same login session as localhost?

Comment: Does anyone have a clue? Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you must be using the [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) package. How to mount the system cookes were referring to a domain is this.

```
app.use(session({ 
  secret: "something", 
  // domain: '.app.localhost', <-- This Don't put into the cookie
  store : new RedisStore({
    host: '.app.localhost',
    port : 9200 ,
    client: redisClient
  }),
  cookie : {
    maxAge : 604800 // one week
    domain: 'app.localhost', //<-- This put into the cookie the domain
  }
}));
```